# How do I view my own number in Windows Phone 7.8?

Tags: 7.8

I am currently using WP 7.8 (HTC Ultimate) and I tried the following:

- Settings > Applications > Phone
- Settings > About > More info

And I couldn't find my phone number in these locations.

How can I check my own phone number?

Comment: Your service provider may have some service command to get your own number.

Comment: There is no feature like this for now in Win Phone. You can use your service provider's service command to get number

Comment: @NagaHarishMovva There is such an option, per my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>applications</kbd> > <kbd>Phone</kbd>
*should* show it as the first option, above the Voicemail number (as tested on a HTC Titan)

If it's not showing, it may not have been set as an option on the SIM card, so you may need to contact your telephone network.